# Loading initial values in knockoutjs in wake of subscriptions

Tags: knockout.js

I am using knockoutjs and have two dropdown boxes.
One of them is depending on the other. This alone works fine but I now want to set the initial values and their selected value.

Since I subscribe to a change in the first dropdown box to load the second dropdown box I am not only loading the data twice now, I also loose my initial selection in the second dropdown box.
The reason for this is that I have to clear the selection of the second dropdown whenever the first changes its values. Otherwise the wrong value might be preselected.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/sturm/6Mp33/31/

```
<select name="model" data-bind="options: models, value: selectedModel, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
<select name="makes" data-bind="options: makes, value: selectedMake, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>

function viewModel(initialModels, initialSelectedModel, initialMakes, initialSelectedMake) {
    var self = this;

    self.models = ko.observableArray(initialModels);
    self.selectedModel = ko.observable(initialSelectedModel);
    self.makes = ko.observableArray(initialMakes);
    self.selectedMake = ko.observable(initialSelectedMake);

    self.selectedModel.subscribe(function() {
        // This runs after the initial data and clears the selection
        if (self.selectedModel()) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/echo/json/',
                data: {
                    json: ko.toJSON(makeData[self.selectedModel()-1])
                },
                context: this,
                success: function(data) {
                    self.makes(data);
                    // The folowing line is the problem
                    self.selectedMake(undefined);
                },
                dataType: 'json'
            });
        } else {
            self.makes.removeAll();
        }
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel(modelData, 2, makeData[1], 2));
```

How can you cleanly set initial values without loading twice and keeping the selection?

Comment: Your code is not working because you are using an ancient version of KO: v1.3.0rc. It is working fine with the latest v2.2.1 version: http://jsfiddle.net/6Mp33/37/. So the solution is to upgrade KnockOut. By the way with the version v1.3.0rc you can make it work with passing the index as a string so `ko.applyBindings(new viewModel(modelData, "2", makeData[1], 2));`. But still voting to close as too localized.

Comment: A ugly way of doing this is to have the server send in a variable called first load and then the subscribes can do a check that says if(!firstLoad) then do the subscribe stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I thought the latest link would give me an up to date version, so I guess it really should be closed / invalidated.

Answer (score 2):

Just adding Nemesv's answer from the comment to get this closed

**Update Knockout**